# openMPI data type portability

Tags: c++, c, mpi, openmpi

[FAQ #20](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=all) says:

> As of v1.1, Open MPI requires that the size of C, C++, and Fortran
>   datatypes be the same on all platforms within a single parallel
>   application with the exception of types represented by MPI_BOOL and
>   MPI_LOGICAL -- size differences in these types between processes are
>   properly handled. Endian differences between processes in a single MPI
>   job are properly and automatically handled.
>
> Prior to v1.1, Open MPI did not include any support for data size or
>   endian heterogeneity.

Does it mean that MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG must be either 32 bit on all hosts or 64 bit on all host? My cluster consists of 32 bit and 64 bit Linux servers. What is best way to insure that `long` and `unsigned long` has the same size on all hosts? Maybe I should use only `int` and 'long long' only? Those are 32 and 64 bits respectively on all hosts. Is it OK to have inconsistent data size as long as it is not used?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be mentioned that MPI 1.1 is a bit old. If you have to use MPI 1.1 then I'm not sure, but if you can use MPI 2 then have a look at section 3.3 of the [MPI 2.2 standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report.pdf). From my understanding it is not required that for example a MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG be the same size (same number of bytes) on all hosts. For send/receive operations the MPI datatypes are not defined to be a specific size; they are defined to correspond to a specific datatype in C or Fortran. So for example MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG corresponds to *unsigned long int* in C (table 3.2). Since C does not guarantee any specific size (just that it's at least 32 bits in C99) for *unsigned long int*, neither does MPI.

To back this up we have a direct quote from page 38 of the standard:

> [...] If the sender and receiver execute in different environments,
>   then the ten real values that are fetched from the send buffer will
>   be converted to the representation for reals on the receiver site 
>   before they are stored in the receive buffer. While the number of
>   real elements fetched from the send buffer equal the number of real
>   elements stored in the receive buffer, the number of bytes stored
>   need not equal the number of bytes loaded. **For example, the sender
>   may use a four byte representation and the receiver an eight byte
>   representation for reals.**

The sizes defined in table 13.2 on page 433 are only valid for the "external32" data representations (for file interoperability) and are not valid elsewhere as far as I can tell.

Comment: The official FAQ says *As of v1.1*, so what you should apply to 1.1 as well. Note, that the FAQ also says *Prior to v1.1, Open MPI did not include any support for data size or endian heterogeneity.* I guess it means that data size can be heterogeneous too. I will run small example to confirm it, but 99% sure that it is true and therefore mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

The OpenMPI data types should be the same regardless of the architecture. For instance, a `MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG` is defined to be 32-bit and an `MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG` is 64-bit (see for instance here: http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report.pdf, page 433. `MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG` is defined to have 4 bytes).

The MPI spec has additionally `MPI_INT64_T` and friends, so there is no guesswork involved.

Comment: Does it mean that boost manual is wrong? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html  singed long int is 8 bytes on my platform (GCC on Linux 64 bit), but MPI_LONG should be used with 32 bit signed integers.

Comment: Never used Boost.MPI, only basic MPI. I assume (GUESSING HERE!) that if you pass a long (64-bit) around, and it gets transferred as MPI_LONG, only 32-bit are guaranteed to be transferred. That would definitely make some kind of sense and explain the stuff from page 38 quoted by Quantumboredom. Should be easy enough to try ;)

Comment: Sorry, I think you got it wrong. MPI data types are platform dependent to reflect C data types, but MPI performs representation conversion automatically. Anyway, I appreciate your input.

Comment: Yes, but that pretty much means if you put in a 64-bit long on an x64, you'll get a 32-bit long on a x86 machine, so you should definitely use the sized types only.

Comment: Sized types are great, but don't see them in mpi-2. Looks like it is a new feature in mpi-2.2.